# How to force pascal case with Oracle's Entity Framework support?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, orm

Oracle's entity framework support is making all class names upper case and carrying over underscore.
So ORDER_ITEMS table becomes ORDER_ITEMS in class name. but I want to use Pascal case for class names.

ORDER_ITEMS ==> OrderItems is wanted.

How can I change the default naming rule?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Around 2 weeks ago, I was tasked with getting rid of Linq Connect as our Data provider to using EF for our ORM operations. Well, as well all know it, things are never easy when Microsoft and Oracle are involved, as they don’t play well together. It was up to the savvy developer to find a solution for Pascal Casing and Pluralization, so that the Entities generated from the Oracle database matched our standards. We didn't want table names with underscores to show up on our Models. It took a little bit of thought and development to finally come to a good solution. The end result was manipulating the EDMX file and then running the T4 templates to make the magic happen. Our end result converted all the entities and their properties to Pascal casing. It also converted all the Stored functions to Pascal casing. Navigation properties to collection were all also pluralized. Here are the steps and the code snippet to follow. Hope this helps some one in the coding community and you can always reach out to me at seafarer_007 on twitter with helpful comments or suggestions. Here it is: 1. Generate the EDMX using the EF Data Model item. I used EF 5.0 in Visual Studio 2012. 2. Write a console app that manipulates the EDMX and the designer files. I have added references to both in the App Config. 3. That should be it, and you will have Pascal cased and Pluralized entities. You can always tweak the Pascal case method to your desires. 4. I tested the code on Visual Studio 2012 and EF 5.0. 5. Caveat : Works with only a single worded namespace without dots, basically you can’t have OrgName.DeptName.Namespace for the Model, it will only handle OrgName, however, you can tweak the Pascal Casing Method to resolve that.

Console Application code below:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string pathFile = string.Empty;
        string designFile = string.Empty;


        //EDMX File location
        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EDMX"] != null)
        {
            pathFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EDMX"].ToString();
        }

        //Designer location for EF 5.0
        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EDMXDiagram"] != null)
        {
            designFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EDMXDiagram"].ToString();
        }





        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(pathFile);


        const string CSDLNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm";
        const string MSLNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs";

        XElement csdl = xdoc.Descendants(XName.Get("Schema", CSDLNamespace)).First();
        XElement msl = xdoc.Descendants(XName.Get("Mapping", MSLNamespace)).First();



        #region CSDL
        foreach (var entitySet in csdl.Element(XName.Get("EntityContainer", CSDLNamespace)).Elements(XName.Get("EntitySet", CSDLNamespace)))
        {
            entitySet.Attribute("Name").Value = PascalCase(entitySet.Attribute("Name").Value);
            entitySet.Attribute("EntityType").Value = PascalCase(entitySet.Attribute("EntityType").Value);
        }
        foreach (var associationSet in csdl.Element(XName.Get("EntityContainer", CSDLNamespace)).Elements(XName.Get("AssociationSet", CSDLNamespace)))
        {
            foreach (var end in associationSet.Elements(XName.Get("End", CSDLNamespace)))
            {
                end.Attribute("EntitySet").Value = PascalCase(end.Attribute("EntitySet").Value);
            }
        }

        foreach (var funtionSet in csdl.Element(XName.Get("EntityContainer", CSDLNamespace)).Elements(XName.Get("FunctionImport", CSDLNamespace)))
        {

            funtionSet.Attribute("Name").Value = PascalCase(funtionSet.Attribute("Name").Value);

        }

        foreach (var entityType in csdl.Elements(XName.Get("EntityType", CSDLNamespace)))
        {
            entityType.Attribute("Name").Value = PascalCase(entityType.Attribute("Name").Value);

            foreach (var key in entityType.Elements(XName.Get("Key", CSDLNamespace)))
            {
                foreach (var propertyRef in key.Elements(XName.Get("PropertyRef", CSDLNamespace)))
                {
                    propertyRef.Attribute("Name").Value = PascalCase(propertyRef.Attribute("Name").Value);
                }
            }

            foreach (var property in entityType.Elements(XName.Get("Property", CSDLNamespace)))
            {
                property.Attribute("Name").Value = PascalCase(property.Attribute("Name").Value);
            }

            foreach (var navigationProperty in entityType.Elements(XName.Get("NavigationProperty", CSDLNamespace)))
            {
                navigationProperty.Attribute("Name").Value = PascalCase(navigationProperty.Attribute("Name").Value, true, true); 
            }

        }
        foreach (var association in csdl.Elements(XName.Get("Association", CSDLNamespace)))
        {
            foreach (var end in association.Elements(XName.Get("End", CSDLNamespace)))
            {
                end.Attribute("Type").Value = PascalCase(end.Attribute("Type").Value);
            }               

            foreach(var refs in association.Elements(XName.Get("ReferentialConstraint", CSDLNamespace)))
            {

                foreach (var pri in refs.Elements(XName.Get("Principal", CSDLNamespace)))
                {

                    foreach (var proref in pri.Elements(XName.Get("PropertyRef", CSDLNamespace)))
                    {

                        proref.Attribute("Name").Value = PascalCase(proref.Attribute("Name").Value);
                    }

                }

                foreach (var pri in refs.Elements(XName.Get("Dependent", CSDLNamespace)))
                {

                    foreach (var proref in pri.Elements(XName.Get("PropertyRef", CSDLNamespace)))
                    {

                        proref.Attribute("Name").Value = PascalCase(proref.Attribute("Name").Value);
                    }

                }


            }



        }
        #endregion

        #region MSL

        foreach (var entitySetMapping in msl.Element(XName.Get("EntityContainerMapping", MSLNamespace)).Elements(XName.Get("EntitySetMapping", MSLNamespace)))
        {
            entitySetMapping.Attribute("Name").Value = PascalCase(entitySetMapping.Attribute("Name").Value);

            foreach (var entityTypeMapping in entitySetMapping.Elements(XName.Get("EntityTypeMapping", MSLNamespace)))
            {
                entityTypeMapping.Attribute("TypeName").Value = PascalCase(entityTypeMapping.Attribute("TypeName").Value);
                foreach
                (var scalarProperty in
                (entityTypeMapping.Element(XName.Get("MappingFragment", MSLNamespace))).Elements(XName.Get("ScalarProperty", MSLNamespace))
                )
                {
                    scalarProperty.Attribute("Name").Value = PascalCase(scalarProperty.Attribute("Name").Value);
                }

            }
        }
        foreach (var associationSetMapping in msl.Element(XName.Get("EntityContainerMapping", MSLNamespace)).Elements(XName.Get("AssociationSetMapping", MSLNamespace)))
        {
            foreach (var endProperty in associationSetMapping.Elements(XName.Get("EndProperty", MSLNamespace)))
            {
                foreach (var scalarProperty in endProperty.Elements(XName.Get("ScalarProperty", MSLNamespace)))
                {
                    scalarProperty.Attribute("Name").Value = PascalCase(scalarProperty.Attribute("Name").Value);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var functionSetMapping in msl.Element(XName.Get("EntityContainerMapping", MSLNamespace)).Elements(XName.Get("FunctionImportMapping", MSLNamespace)))
        {
            functionSetMapping.Attribute("FunctionImportName").Value = PascalCase(functionSetMapping.Attribute("FunctionImportName").Value);
        }
        #endregion

        xdoc.Save(pathFile);


        XmlDocument designXml = new XmlDocument();

        designXml.Load(designFile);      


        XmlNamespaceManager dsMan = new XmlNamespaceManager(designXml.NameTable);
        dsMan.AddNamespace("edmx", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx");
        dsMan.AddNamespace("d", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx");


        #region Designer

        XmlNodeList entitySet1 = designXml.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//d:Diagrams", dsMan);

        foreach (XmlNode xn in entitySet1)
        {

            foreach (XmlElement xp in xn.ChildNodes)
            {

                foreach (XmlElement z in xp.ChildNodes)
                {

                    if (z.Attributes[0].Name == "EntityType")
                    {

                        z.Attributes[0].Value = PascalCase(z.Attributes[0].Value.ToString(), true);

                    }


                }

            }


        }

        designXml.Save(designFile);


        #endregion

    }

    #region Pluralization


    public static string Pluralize(string name)
    {

   return System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices.PluralizationService.CreateService(new CultureInfo("en-US")).Pluralize(name);
    }



    #endregion



    #region Pascal Casing

    public static string PascalCase(StructuralType type, bool sanitizeName = true)
    {
        if (type == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return PascalCase(type.Name, sanitizeName);
    }


    public static string PascalCase(EdmMember member, bool sanitizeName = true)
    {
        if (member == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return PascalCase(member.Name, sanitizeName);
    }

    public static string PascalCase(string name, bool sanitizeName = true, bool pluralize = false)
    {

       // if pascal case exists
       // exit function

        Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^[A-Z][a-z]+(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)*$");

        string pascalTest = name;

        if (name.Contains("."))
        {
            string[] test  = new string[]{};
            test = name.Split('.');

            if(rgx.IsMatch(test[1].ToString()))
            {
                return name;
            }

        }
        else
        {

            if (rgx.IsMatch(name))
            {
                return name;
            }

        }

        //Check for dot notations in namespace

        bool contains = false;
        string[] temp = new string[] { };
        var namespc = string.Empty;

        if (name.Contains("."))
        {
            contains = true;
            temp = name.Split('.');
            namespc = temp[0];

        }

        if (contains)
        {
            name = temp[1];
        }

        name = name.ToLowerInvariant();

        string result = name;
        bool upperCase = false;

        result = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
        {
            if (name[i] == ' ' || name[i] == '_')
            {
                upperCase = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (i == 0 || upperCase)
                {
                    result += name[i].ToString().ToUpperInvariant();
                    upperCase = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    result += name[i];
                }
            }
        }


        if (contains)
        {


            result = namespc.ToString() + "." + result;



        }

        if (pluralize)
        {
            result = Pluralize(result);
        }


        return result;
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: what is this designFile path you mentioned ?

Answer (score 0):

it's not available yet.
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9681138

Answer (score 0):

If it is a code first approach, Suppose you are using any inline queries just include the before and after naming objects escape sequence of quote.It  will allows.