# CamelCase EntityFramework types generation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, t4

I have a project EF6 with DB first.
SPs and Tables on DB are very bad named, like TABLE_DATA and stored procedures as GET_DATA_FROM_TABLE.

When I map the sp GET_DATA_FROM_TABLE on EF, I got function import declaration as follow on edmx file:

```
<FunctionImport Name="GET_DATA_FROM_TABLE" ReturnType="Collection(MyModel.GET_DATA_FROM_TABLE_Result)">
```

On Context.cs file, the function declaration is as follow:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<GET_DATA_FROM_TABLE_Result> GET_DATA_FROM_TABLE(..params here..)
```

I already found the way to generate the CamelCase function name on context.cs file by changing the T4 template. (also parameters needs to be corrected)

Now I have a nive .cs files generated from T4 templates but I can't find a way to also force EF to generate nice names on edmw file for imported functions.

any way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

i got inspired on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24069445/810917
and now I have console program to parse and modify edmx file on all function import declaration and params to map there to make them match the corresponding types generated .cs files from the modified T4 templates to ensure PascalCamelCase everyowhere are the same.
it works nice !