# how to generate classes and property names in Pascal Case while generating EF DB First classes from Oracle Database

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, ef-code-first, edmx

I have an oracle database that has tables names and column names in all upper case. When i generate EDMX using Entity Framework database first approach, it generates all the classes and their property names in all upper case as well.

Is there a way to generate these classes and property names in PasalCase ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force pascal case with Oracle's Entity Framework support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694659/how-to-force-pascal-case-with-oracles-entity-framework-support)

Comment: it just generates first letter of everything upper case. May be there is some VS UI extension that can do that ?