# how can we control EF Database First generated class and property names

Tags: entity-framework, ef-database-first

I have an Oracle database that has all its tables and columns in all Upper-Case.

For example table STUDENT has FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME and DATEOFBIRTH

when i generate classes using EF Database First approach, i get all classes and names in Upper-Case as well.

answer here

[How to force pascal case with Oracle's Entity Framework support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694659/how-to-force-pascal-case-with-oracles-entity-framework-support)

did not helped as it only generates names with only First letter in upper case instead of FirstName or LastName.

I thought of doing it manually. Is there a way i can write something in OnModelCreating so that every time i generate edmx i get the names right?

If i change name after generation its going to override next time i update it from database.

Comment: For any automated solution to distinguish individual words in an upper-case string you'd need a pretty advanced solution using a (language) dictionary. Alternatively you can create a (C#) dictionary containing all field names and their Pascal-cased equivalents. This dictionary can be used in a modified tt file.

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper may be able help with this, though I have not used Re# in a while or the naming convention feature. (see: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Inspect_the_Whole_Solution_for_Naming_Style_Compliance.html) Tell it you want UpperCamelCase and run it across the generated code. There may be other plug-ins available with this capability.

EF isn't going to do it as I doubt they'd be trying to determine word boundaries for naming. howwillitknowhowmanywordsareinhere? :)